# Scrapy: repeating request for 440 status code

Tags: python, request, scrapy, web-crawler

Is there a way in scrapy how to repeat a request, if the response status code is 440?

Sometimes the server i am trying to scrape responds with 440 code and the I can´t scrape the data.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [scrapy documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/) you can add and configure the `RetryMiddleware` to behave the way you want.

The settings you will want to change are: `RETRY_TIMES` and `RETRY_HTTP_CODES`. Specially the second one where the defaults are: `[500, 502, 503, 504, 408]`, so there you just need to add `440` to the list.

Check more details about the middleware [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#module-scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry)